# Multiple Kendo DropDownList controls with same datasource using memoryCache .Net Core

Tags: kendo-ui, .net-core, dropdown

I have multiple Yes/No dropdown lists on a view using .net core. When I'm using the "normal" data source all is fine:

```
DropDownListCode um = new DropDownListCode(_context);
var result = um.GetYesNoNAList();
return Json(result);
```

But when I use the memoryCache, only the first dropdown loads.

```
public JsonResult GetYesNoNA()
    {
        IEnumerable<DropDownListCode.NameValueStr> list;
        if (_memoryCache.TryGetValue(Constants.YesNoNACacheKey, out list))
        {
            return Json(list);
        }
        else
        {
            MemoryCacheEntryOptions cacheExpirationOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions();
            cacheExpirationOptions.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
            cacheExpirationOptions.Priority = CacheItemPriority.Normal;
            DropDownListCode um = new DropDownListCode(_context);
            var result = um.GetYesNoNAList();
            _memoryCache.Set(Constants.YesNoNACacheKey, result);
            return Json(result);
        }
    }
```

How can I fix this?

I have looked at two other entries in Stackoverflow for multiple dropdowns with same datasource but they didn't answer this specific question.

Comment: Isn't this a bit overkill to populate a pretty static JSON object of values `Yes`, `No`, `N/A`? For this particular method you have above I would probably say it is less overhead to just put the response object right in that method as a one liner (ex `return Json(new object ({"Yes", "No", "N/A"}));` )

Comment: I agree Svek, but it's not my project... lol... it would be nice to know what the issue is though for when I run into this with data I do need to get from the db

Comment: Maybe reword the question and change the example code to be more about your memory cache problems?